# Image Tooltips on Vega Charts

Tags: javascript, vega

I'm a d3 developer getting to grips with VEGA charts.  I want to add a tooltip with an image - any thoughts on how to do this?

For instance, with this example:

https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/bar-chart/

Assuming there is an extra variable in the data with a url:

```
  {"category": "A", "amount": 28, "image_url": "http://www.mywebsite.com/myimage.png"}
```

Easy enough to do in d3 but just can't quite work it out in Vega.  All help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone else comes across the same, I've found an answer.

The trick is to access the view in the vegaEmbed statement.

```
vegaEmbed('#vis', spec).then(function(result) {
     // access view as result.view
     var view = result.view;

     view.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event, item) {

           ////catch the data here:  item.datum.my_field_name.
           ////now you can select and populate your tooltip div

     });


}).catch(console.error);
```

Once you've got this, you can create a div tooltip in the normal way outside of this call and select and populate it using the id or class.

Easy when you know how!

Comment: Hi Bmil, I have the same problem. Can you give a complete example?

Comment: Sorry - I just replied and it disappeared when I logged on.    Impossible to answer as I can't upload the complete example due to client confidentiality.  Essentially, I defined a hidden div in the html with various elements including an image tag with the id 'my_img'.  On the event, I made the div visible and changed the image via document.getElementById('my_img').src = item.datum.image  You need to add an error checker at the start to only do this if item !== null.  Vega is tricky to get your head around - persist as it can produce beautiful, quick results once you've got your head round it.